# Google Cloud - TPU Node Resource Name

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tpu

Im trying to create a Google Cloud TPU node using [TPU client API](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/tpu/latest/google.cloud.tpu_v1.types.CreateNodeRequest)  and I cannot figure out the parent resource name of a TPU node in Google Cloud.

Below you can find the full code I'm using to create the node and I'm struggling to understand wht should be the value of the `parent` attribute of the `CreateNodeRequest` class:

```
def create_tpu_node(parent_resource_name, node_name, accelerator_type, runtime_version):
# Create a client
client = tpu_v2alpha1.TpuClient()

# Initialize request argument(s)
node = tpu_v2alpha1.Node()
node.name = node_name
node.accelerator_type = accelerator_type
node.runtime_version = runtime_version

request = tpu_v2alpha1.CreateNodeRequest(
    parent=parent_resource_name,
    node=node,
)

# Make the request
operation = client.create_node(request=request)

print("Waiting for operation to complete...")

response = operation.result()

# Handle the response
return response
```

I have tried these parent resource names, among other combinations:

1. *projects/my-project-id/zones/europe-west4-a/tpus*
2. *my-project-id/zones/europe-west4-a/tpus*

And I always get, respectively, one of the following errors:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Malformed name: 'projects/my-project-id/zones/europe-west4-a/tpus/nodes/'
```

or

```
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Invalid resource field value in the request.
```

I really have no clue how to get the TPU node parent resource name, or even a TPU node resource name. Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT**: I also tried with the following parent resource name `projects/my-project-id/locations/europe-west4-a`, and I still get the gRPC error below:

```
status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT details = "Malformed name: 'projects/my-project-id/locations/europe-west4-a/nodes/'" debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1645875905.514000000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:142.251.36.42:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1068,"grpc_message":"Malformed name: 'projects/my-project-id/locations/europe-west4-a/nodes/'","grpc_status":3}
```

Comment: Try this string modified for your project and location: **projects/example-project/locations/us-east1**

Comment: Hi @John Hanley, I tried that but I get the error: google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Malformed name.
I also tried other combinations (see my edited post). Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the expected format of `parent` in the documentation for the underlying API method: [projects.locations.nodes.create](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/reference/rest/v2alpha1/projects.locations.nodes/create#http-request).

`parent` should be formatted as `projects/*/locations/*`. That is, change `zones` to `locations` and remove the `/tpus` from the end.

Edit: adding some example code below

I tried exactly the following (except for project and TPU names) on a [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell):

```py
from google.cloud import tpu_v2alpha1

req = tpu_v2alpha1.CreateNodeRequest(
  parent='projects/my-project-id/locations/europe-west4-a', 
  node_id='test-tpu',
  node=tpu_v2alpha1.Node(
    accelerator_type='v2-8',
    runtime_version='v2-alpha',
    network_config=tpu_v2alpha1.NetworkConfig(
      enable_external_ips=True)))

op = client.create_node(req)
# Shows TPU created successfully
op.result()
```

I ran this example with the `google-cloud-tpu` package at `1.3.2`

Comment: Hi, I tried also with that format, and I still get the error below (btw, Im using conda virtual env)

`status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
details = "Malformed name: 'projects/my-project-id/locations/europe-west4-a/nodes/'"
debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1645875905.514000000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:142.251.36.42:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1068,"grpc_message":"Malformed name: 'projects/my-project-id/locations/europe-west4-a/nodes/'","grpc_status":3}"`

Comment: It looks like you need to remove `nodes` from the path. i.e. change `projects/my-project-id/locations/europe-west4-a/nodes/` to `projects/my-project-id/locations/europe-west4-a/`

Comment: Hi, I have the exact same issue.
To be clear, the author and I are *not* adding the trailing /nodes in the parent string, simply `parent="projects/*/locations/*"`, as requested in the responses to this issue. 
But we can still see /nodes in the "Malformed name" error. Maybe it is added by the library?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Can you try the example code I added to my answer and tell me if that works?

Comment: Hi, with your example code, it now works for me in 1.3.1 too.

Thanks a lot